# How to return a stream with server for nodejs (serverjs.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using https://serverjs.io/documentation/reply/

I can't figure out how best to return streams? The ctx.res is a writable stream? I would like to take full advantage of the stream (transform and not read all into memory)...sockets?

I can't find any documentation. Plenty about returning streams but not with this. I'd like to use server.js because in all other respects it seems pretty decent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creator of server.js here. Sorry for taking so long to answer I didn't find this question before. Though I think I've read it somewhere else before?

But let's get to it, it was quite more counter-intuitive than what I expected, but not impossible. You [have the code example here](https://github.com/franciscop/server/tree/master/examples/stream) now:

```js
const server = require('server');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const img = path.resolve('../../test/logo.png');
const stream = (read, write) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  read.pipe(write).on('error', reject).on('end', resolve);
});

server(ctx => {
  return stream(fs.createReadStream(img), ctx.res);
});
```

Server will not work nicely with streams, but it will work perfectly with Promises so we wrap it all in a promise that will be resolved when the streaming ends.

Why/how are you using this? If you [open an issue with a common case](https://github.com/franciscop/server) I'll probably add this as a new reply type since it seems fairly easy to add and test, while still within the scope of the library.

To answer your sub-question, `ctx.res` is literally express' `res`, but the problem is that you *have to return* something. That is why I'm wrapping it around a promise that will resolve only when it's finished streaming.

Comment: Should that better be `(resolve, reject) => fs.createReadStream(img).pipe(ctx.res).on('end', resolve).on('error', reject)`? Thus, with error handling.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are right, feel free to edit the answer/open an Issue or do a PR. I'll fix it otherwise when I get to my computer.